# How to restore postgres with base backup and wal files

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am using rsync and pg_basebackup to copy wal file and base.
My rsync runs every minute and copy WAL files from pg_xlog and every end of the day i run pg_basebackup to get the base folder.

Now i need to know how to restore the postgres back to normal using base backup and wal files.

Comment: This seems unconventional.  WAL files usually get archived up on demand via archive_command, or by streaming.  Could you give the defails of this, as well as of the pg_basebackup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shutdown the cluster , restore(unzip and copy) the files & folders from `Basebackup` to data directory. Remove old files present in pg_wal directory in the file system backup.

If there are any unarchived WAL segment files recovered from crashed cluster, copy them to pg_wal directory.

Set the restore_command (This command is used to retrieve archive segment of the WAL Files) and recovery_target based on the PG version you are on.

Temporarily modify pg_hba.conf to prevent ordinary users from connecting. Stop / block all the connections.

Make the `recovery.signal` ( if version >12) and start the cluster.

Modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow users to connect to the database.